# monitoring the MSMQ outgoing queue?

Tags: powershell, monitoring, msmq

I am trying to monitor the outgoing queue of several servers with a script but can't find the right name / path to do so.

here is what i tried :

formatName:Direct=OS:Servername\outgoing_queue$

got the following error : 
« Format name is invalid. »

formatName:Direct=OS:servername\outgoing_queue$

Error : « A workgroup installation computer does not support the operation. »

.\outgoing_queue$

error: « A workgroup installation computer does not support the operation. »

Does anyone here experience that ? Do you know where i can find the right name / path to monitor that queue ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cmdlet Get-MsmqOutgoingQueue:

```
Get-MsmqOutgoingQueue -Name "Name of the queue, wildcards supported"
```

This cmdlet gets outgoing queues that are local to the computer on which you run the cmdlet. If you do not specify parameters, this cmdlet gets all outgoing queues of the host computer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the command does not work cause i'm on a windows 2008 server, i still manage to have a list with the command gwmi -class Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue  but i can only see the name of the private and system queue, not the outgoing queue. As I understand it, the outgoing queue only exist when the receiver can't receive all the messages from the server. It would be normal in my case that at this time, there is no outgoing queue, but how do i manage to get the name of it, to be adapt my script to monitor the outgoing queue when it should be ?

Comment: The WMI class can just retrieve the private and system queues, So I don't find other ways to do that. This cmdlet is available from Windows Server 2012 or powershell 3.1 so I think it will be better if you upgrade powershell.